# how to add column1 column2 ,column 3 to total column in a single query

Tags: sql

I created the student table. It has four mark columns and one total column. If I insert four mark column values, how can I have the sum automatically added in the totals column?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Please make your question clear with all the details. Also please add the code/script which you tried and what errors you are getting. And as for starting points you should not store total of three columns in fourth column, instead whenever required just do the `SUM` aggregation with select statement.

Comment: I think the question is regarding a computed column. Suggested answer below.

Comment: Tried to edit question to be clearer. Hoping I succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you, you are asking about a computed column.

It gets calculated when requested, and does not take up any additional space in the table, when inserting rows.

In the example below, TotalColumn will automatically contain the sum of Col1-4.

When you insert, skip TotalColumn.

When you select, it will be calcluated automatically, and returned.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTbl
( Col1 INT
 ,Col2 INT
 ,Col3 INT
 ,Col4 INT
 ,TotalColumn AS Col1+Col2+Col3+Col4
)
```